# Is it possible to connect to a .NET remoting server from an Android application?

Tags: android, .net

I have an application that uses .NET remoting (Activator) to create a server, is it possible for an Android application to connect to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the best option would be to convert the remoting service to a WCF service in order to expose a more common way of communicating.

Or create a WCF wrapper service that would talk to the remoting service and relay the responses.